# Text cursor is displayed on all websites

Tags: windows

So when I woke up today I noticed that I get the cursor everywhere on every webpage when I click stuff, how did I enable it and how do I disable it? As it is quite bothering :)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(assuming this is Firefox)

It sounds like you accidentally enabled [Caret Browsing.](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Accessibility.browsewithcaret)

You can disable this feature by pressing <kbd>F7</kbd> (or <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> on Mac) or by going to *Options/Preferences* → *General* → *Browsing* and removing the checkmark for *Always use the cursor keys to navigate within pages*.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/970659